# Array com Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array

Estou tentando fazer um sorteio de musicas porem ele sempre exibe a ultima musica cadastrada no banco de dados

```
$sql = "SELECT nome FROM CadMusicas"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conecta); 


while($consulta = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
   $antigos= array($consulta[nome]);
   $numMusicas= sizeof($antigos);
   # Primeiro ganhador
   $sorteado[1] = $antigos[rand(0,$numMusicas- 1)];
} 


echo "<b>Musicas Sorteadas:</b> <br />";
echo "<b>1°</b> - " . $sorteado[1] . "<br />";
```

Comment: "... sempre exibe a ultima musica cadastrada no banco de dados" ... e qual é sua duvida? qual o problema? no que quer ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o melhor a se fazer é usar o `RAND`.

```
SELECT nome FROM CadMusicas ORDER BY RAND()
```

Isso irá retornar os registros numa ordem aleatória, isso irá depender de como está estruturado o seu banco de dados, cada musica deve ser uma 'linha'!

Se for apenas um cadastro faça isso:

```
$sql = 'SELECT nome FROM CadMusicas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conecta); 

$consulta = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $consulta['nome'];
```

> Nota: O RAND tem uma performance terrivelmente ruim em grandes bancos
>   de dados, acho que não é seu caso, mas uma solução é usar isso:

```
SELECT nome FROM CadMusicas WHERE RAND()<(SELECT ((1/COUNT(*))*10) FROM CadMusicas) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: deu certo só que eu preciso que isto seja repetido 3x e existem momentos que ele se repete e não pode! como ficaria isto?

Comment: tentei usar o distinct  mas não adiantou "SELECT distinct nome FROM CadMusicas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"

Comment: O distinct só serve na query. O MySQL não salva o que foi gerado a não ser que você mesmo salve o valor gerado numa tabela, então use `NOT IN`. Você tem duas alternativas, além de criar tal tabela. Use `LIMIT 3`, isso tera 3 resultados, use  `nome NOT IN()`, veja no manual do MySQL em http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html. Dessa forma você armazena em session ou em variável o nome anterior e ele não seria selecionar isso.